# Currency Denomination program

Tags: java

I'm working on an assignment, and for the most part I have already written the majority of the code.  The program asks the user to enter an amount in dollars and cents.  The program, then, will break up the amount into different denominations.  I got it working earlier, but after formatting my print statements, and doing a few tests, I realized that there are no values being printed for the coins.  Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Below is my code with output.

```
import java.util.*;

public class BillBreaker {

    // Instantiate Scanner class for reading keyboard input
    public static Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // instantiate Scanner class for reading keyboard input

        double orgAmount;
        int orgPennies; // pennies part of the amount
        int remPennies;
        long orgDollars;
        // variables for bills of denominations.
        long hundreds;
        int fifties, twenties, tens, fives, twos, ones;

        //variables for keeping track of coins
        int pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters;

        // print greeting and prompt user for input.
        System.out.println("Given an amount in dollars and cents, I will find");
        System.out.println("a combination of bills and coins:\n");
        System.out.println("Enter a dollar amount including cents.");

        // read amount of dollars and pennies.
        orgAmount = kbd.nextDouble();

        // printf is used to format user input into dollars and cents with comma delimiter
        System.out.printf("Amount you entered in Dollars and cents: $%,.2f\n  ",orgAmount);


        orgDollars = (long)orgAmount;
        System.out.printf("\nDollars Part of Original Amount: $%,d\n", orgDollars);

        //extract the pennies from in orgAmount
        orgPennies = (int)((orgAmount % 100));
        System.out.println("pennies part of orginal amount: " + orgPennies);

        //Extract and print the number of \$100 bills from the dollar amount. 
        //Reduce the dollar amount to account for \$100 bills
        hundreds = (long)orgAmount/100;
        orgAmount = orgAmount%100;
        System.out.printf ("Number of $100 bills: %,d\n",hundreds);

        //Extract and print the number of \$50 bills.  Reduce the dollar amount
        //to account for \$50 bills.
        fifties = (int)orgAmount/50;
        orgAmount = orgAmount%50;
        System.out.println ("Number of $50 bills: " + fifties);

        //Extract and print the number of \$20 bills.  Reduce the dollar amount
        //to account for \$20 bills.
        twenties = (int) orgAmount/20;
        orgAmount = orgAmount%20;
        System.out.println ("Number of $20 bills: " + twenties);

        //Extract and print the number of \$10 bills.  Reduce the dollar amount
        //to account for \$10 bills
        tens = (int) orgAmount/10;
        orgAmount = orgAmount%10;
        System.out.println ("Number of $10 bills: " + tens);

        //Extract and print the number of \$5 bills.  Reduce the dollar amount
        //to account for \$5 bills
        fives = (int) orgAmount/5;
        orgAmount = orgAmount%5;
        System.out.println ("Number of $5 bills: " + fives);

        //Extract and print the number of \$2 bills.  Reduce the dollar amount
        //to account for \$2 bills
        twos = (int) orgAmount/2;
        orgAmount = orgAmount%2;
        System.out.println ("Number of $2 bills: " + twos);

        //Extract and print the number of \$1 bills.  Reduce the dollar amount
        //to account for \$1 bills
        ones = (int) orgAmount/1;
        orgAmount = orgAmount%1;
        System.out.println ("Number of $1 bills: " + ones);

        //Extract and print the number of quarters from the number of pennies. 
        //Reduce the number of pennies to account for the quarters
        quarters = (int) (orgAmount/0.25);
        orgAmount = orgAmount%.25;
        System.out.println ("Number of Quarters: " + quarters);

        //Extract and print the number of dimes from the number of pennies. 
        //Reduce the number of pennies to account for the dimes
        dimes = (int) (orgAmount/0.10);
        orgAmount = orgAmount%.10;
        System.out.println ("Number of Dimes: " + dimes);

        //Extract and print the number of nickels from the number of pennies. 
        //Reduce the number of pennies to account for the nickels
        nickels = (int) (orgAmount/0.05);
        orgAmount = orgAmount%.05;
        System.out.println ("Number of Nickels: " + nickels);

        //Extract and print the number of pennies and terminate the program
        pennies = (int) (orgAmount/0.01);
        orgAmount = orgAmount%.01;
        System.out.println ("Number of Pennies: " + pennies);


    }

}
```

My Output1: Starting amount: 323.55
This gives me the correct amount in the first 3 test outputs below.

```
Given an amount in dollars and cents, I will find
a combination of bills and coins:

Enter a dollar amount including cents.
323.55
Amount you entered in Dollars and cents: $323.55

Dollars Part of Original Amount: $323
pennies part of orginal amount: 23
Number of $100 bills: 3
Number of $50 bills: 0
Number of $20 bills: 1
Number of $10 bills: 0
Number of $5 bills: 0
Number of $2 bills: 1
Number of $1 bills: 1
Number of Quarters: 2
Number of Dimes: 0
Number of Nickels: 1
Number of Pennies: 0
```

Output2: Starting Amount:

```
Given an amount in dollars and cents, I will find
a combination of bills and coins:

Enter a dollar amount including cents.
2335.32
Amount you entered in Dollars and cents: $2,335.32

Dollars Part of Original Amount: $2,335
pennies part of orginal amount: 35
Number of $100 bills: 23
Number of $50 bills: 0
Number of $20 bills: 1
Number of $10 bills: 1
Number of $5 bills: 1
Number of $2 bills: 0
Number of $1 bills: 0
Number of Quarters: 1
Number of Dimes: 0
Number of Nickels: 1
Number of Pennies: 2
```

Output3: Starting Amount: 9879823.92

```
Given an amount in dollars and cents, I will find
a combination of bills and coins:

Enter a dollar amount including cents.
9879823.92
Amount you entered in Dollars and cents: $9,879,823.92

Dollars Part of Original Amount: $9,879,823
pennies part of orginal amount: 23
Number of $100 bills: 98,798
Number of $50 bills: 0
Number of $20 bills: 1
Number of $10 bills: 0
Number of $5 bills: 0
Number of $2 bills: 1
Number of $1 bills: 1
Number of Quarters: 3
Number of Dimes: 1
Number of Nickels: 1
Number of Pennies: 1
```

However, with certain amounts, the output is off by one mainly in the pennies.
Now the revised code was changed during the variable initiation, but I'm not sure if I understood if I needed to use orgPennies instead of all orgAmount?

This is the error output with the pennies being off by one less.

Output4: Starting Amount: 111.11

```
Given an amount in dollars and cents, I will find
a combination of bills and coins:

Enter a dollar amount including cents.
111.11
Amount you entered in Dollars and cents: $111.11

Dollars Part of Original Amount: $111
pennies part of orginal amount: 11
Number of $100 bills: 1
Number of $50 bills: 0
Number of $20 bills: 0
Number of $10 bills: 1
Number of $5 bills: 0
Number of $2 bills: 0
Number of $1 bills: 1
Number of Quarters: 0
Number of Dimes: 1
Number of Nickels: 0
Number of Pennies: 0
```

Maybe I've just been looking at this too long and need to step away for a minute.  I"m sure its going to be very obvious, but again, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm taking a look again and I'm not seeing anything necessarily *wrong* about your output.  The only thing that may be wrong in this case is that there's nothing to indicate what the decimal place is.

Comment: As @Makoto mentioned, there is nothing to indicate decimal place and you can see that on your input. The amount you entered section does not indicate any cents.

Answer (score 1):

```
        orgAmount = (long)orgAmount;
        System.out.printf("\nDollars Part of Original Amount: $%,.0f\n", orgAmount);

        //extract the pennies from in orgAmount
        orgPennies = (int)((orgAmount % 100) * 100);
        System.out.println("pennies part of orginal amount: " + orgPennies);
```

It looks like you are removing the decimal place values from orgAmount before trying to put the value into orgPennies, which shouldn't have a "* 100", and then you forgot to use orgPennies instead of orgAmount to calculate the number of pennies.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the code, but I'm not quite sure if understood the last part of your sentence of how I was not using the orgPennies in the right spots.  Not sure if this is what you ment, but I updated the code above with a few sample outputs that seem to work.  However, for some values, the pennies count is off by one less than it should be.

Comment: I meant you should use the orgPennies value (after *100 and converting to integer) to get the number of dimes nickels and pennies. Otherwise you risk having floating point errors which might be causing your inaccurate results.

Comment: I was a bit confused by the computation yesterday because your sample input had no decimal value.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a double to hold the input amount and do the calculations.  You cannot expect precision to the cent with a double.  You must use a BigDecimal to hold large amounts of money.

Here's a test run after I changed your doubles to BigDecimals.

```
Given an amount in dollars and cents, I will find
a combination of bills and coins:

Enter a dollar amount including cents.
9879823.92
Amount you entered in Dollars and cents: $9,879,823.92

Dollars Part of Original Amount: $9,879,823
pennies part of orginal amount: 92
Number of $100 bills: 98,798
Number of $50 bills: 0
Number of $20 bills: 1
Number of $10 bills: 0
Number of $5 bills: 0
Number of $2 bills: 1
Number of $1 bills: 1
Number of Quarters: 3
Number of Dimes: 1
Number of Nickels: 1
Number of Pennies: 2
```

And here's the code:

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BillBreaker {

    // Instantiate Scanner class for reading keyboard input
    public static Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // instantiate Scanner class for reading keyboard input

        String orgAmount;
        int orgPennies; // pennies part of the amount
        long orgDollars;
        // variables for bills of denominations.
        long hundreds;
        int fifties, twenties, tens, fives, twos, ones;

        // variables for keeping track of coins
        int nickels, dimes, quarters;

        // print greeting and prompt user for input.
        System.out.println("Given an amount in dollars and cents, I will find");
        System.out.println("a combination of bills and coins:\n");
        System.out.println("Enter a dollar amount including cents.");

        // read amount of dollars and pennies.
        orgAmount = kbd.nextLine().trim();
        BigDecimal bdAmount = new BigDecimal(orgAmount);
        bdAmount = bdAmount.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        df.setGroupingUsed(true);
        String result = df.format(bdAmount);

        // println is used to format user input into dollars and cents with
        // comma delimiter
        System.out.println("Amount you entered in Dollars and cents: $"
                + result);

        orgDollars = bdAmount.longValue();
        System.out.printf("\nDollars Part of Original Amount: $%,d\n",
                orgDollars);

        // extract the pennies from in orgAmount
        BigInteger decimal = bdAmount.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE)
                .movePointRight(bdAmount.scale()).abs().toBigInteger();
        orgPennies = decimal.intValue();
        System.out.println("pennies part of orginal amount: " + orgPennies);

        // Extract and print the number of \$100 bills from the dollar amount.
        // Reduce the dollar amount to account for \$100 bills
        hundreds = orgDollars / 100L;
        orgDollars = orgDollars % 100L;
        System.out.printf("Number of $100 bills: %,d\n", hundreds);

        // Extract and print the number of \$50 bills. Reduce the dollar amount
        // to account for \$50 bills.
        fifties = (int) orgDollars / 50;
        orgDollars = orgDollars % 50L;
        System.out.println("Number of $50 bills: " + fifties);

        // Extract and print the number of \$20 bills. Reduce the dollar amount
        // to account for \$20 bills.
        twenties = (int) orgDollars / 20;
        orgDollars = orgDollars % 20L;
        System.out.println("Number of $20 bills: " + twenties);

        // Extract and print the number of \$10 bills. Reduce the dollar amount
        // to account for \$10 bills
        tens = (int) orgDollars / 10;
        orgDollars = orgDollars % 10L;
        System.out.println("Number of $10 bills: " + tens);

        // Extract and print the number of \$5 bills. Reduce the dollar amount
        // to account for \$5 bills
        fives = (int) orgDollars / 5;
        orgDollars = orgDollars % 5L;
        System.out.println("Number of $5 bills: " + fives);

        // Extract and print the number of \$2 bills. Reduce the dollar amount
        // to account for \$2 bills
        twos = (int) orgDollars / 2;
        orgDollars = orgDollars % 2L;
        System.out.println("Number of $2 bills: " + twos);

        // Extract and print the number of \$1 bills. Reduce the dollar amount
        // to account for \$1 bills
        ones = (int) orgDollars;
        System.out.println("Number of $1 bills: " + ones);

        // Extract and print the number of quarters from the number of pennies.
        // Reduce the number of pennies to account for the quarters
        quarters = orgPennies / 25;
        orgPennies = orgPennies % 25;
        System.out.println("Number of Quarters: " + quarters);

        // Extract and print the number of dimes from the number of pennies.
        // Reduce the number of pennies to account for the dimes
        dimes = orgPennies / 10;
        orgPennies = orgPennies % 10;
        System.out.println("Number of Dimes: " + dimes);

        // Extract and print the number of nickels from the number of pennies.
        // Reduce the number of pennies to account for the nickels
        nickels = orgPennies / 5;
        orgPennies = orgPennies % 5;
        System.out.println("Number of Nickels: " + nickels);

        // Extract and print the number of pennies and terminate the program
        System.out.println("Number of Pennies: " + orgPennies);

    }

}
```